# generate random unique token for user id

Tags: node.js, express

I want to generate token as user id and store in database , but how to generate **unique** one?

should I add timestamp `var currentUnixTimestamp = (new Date().getTime() / 1000);` as salt? how to do with crypto?

```
var generateToken = function() {
      return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
        crypto.randomBytes(8, function(error, buf) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            var token = buf.toString('hex');
            fulfill(token);
          }
        });
      });
    };
```

Comment: Doesn't MongoDB already do random token as id for entities ?

Comment: If all user ids are generated from the same server, you can guarantee uniqueness by adding a monotomically increasing and persistently stored counter to each user ID, thus guaranteeing uniqueness.  You can add the `crypto.randomBytes()` to make the user id unpredictable, but the counter will guarantee uniqueness.  Note, you have to store the counter persistently and it has to be used by any server coining the IDs for this to be perfect.

Comment: @Zhang I use postgresql

Comment: @jfriend00 oh, so can I just add the current unixtimestamp after the crypto.randomBytes() then it become unique?

Comment: @user1775888 - you can use the timestamp.  There can be some issues with the timestamp such as multiple calls in close succession can result in retrieving the same timestamp and server clocks can sometimes be off and it's a lot of digits that could just be a few digit counter.  But, it can often be made to work too.

Comment: Why not use an existing library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-v4 or https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid? Statistically, the chance of a collision is nearly non-existant.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks so much ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eight random bytes from a properly seeded crypto library has a low chance of a collision, so you don't usually need to concern yourself with duplicates. In fact, increase that to 16 bytes, and your code is on par with [UUID version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29). This is considered a standard for UUIDs. The chances of a collision are so remote it is not usually worth considering.

If you are going that far though, consider using a standard format UUID, such as [the node package "uuid"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). There are also database-side uuid functions which you can add as default to schemas e.g. [in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/uuid-ossp.html). The advantage is a standardised and well-understood format for your ids, and you won't need to spend any time justifying or maintaining your code for this, just point developers to the standard docs.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try node package uuid   why the uuid each time can be different not duplicate? does the package store some records in somewhere?

Comment: if I try to make shorter like stackoverflow default username any other way to solve it?

Comment: No, there are no records kept by the package, and in fact uniqueness is not guaranteed. But take a look at the probability chart given in the Wikipedia link I show. I work on a database with millions of records across multiple databases, using uuid type 4. We have never had a single issue with duplicate entries. For all intents and purposes you can treat it like it never happens.

Comment: If you make the string shorter, e.g. like a special offer code or car registration, then yes you will need to check for duplicates. Generate the id in a while loop, testing that nothing has same id by trying to read a matching record. Return first code that has no matching record. Provided you have many more possible codes than actual records, this is reasonably efficient/

Answer (score 2):

If you want this token for authentication purposes you should use json web token instead. It will manage for you and its quite efficient.
Only have to include as a middleware .

```
app.use(expressJWT({
        secret: new Buffer("Your-secret-key").toString('base64')
    }).unless({
        //@ pass api without validating
        path: unlessRoutes
    }));
```

You could specify which routes you don't want to to skip in jwt middleware by giving an array in unlessRoutes.

```
var unlessRoutes = [
    '/',
    /\/login/,
    /\/register/,
    /\/customers/,
    /\/customer$/,
    /\/addCustomer/,
    /\/just/,
    /\/search/,
    /\/dynamic/,
    /\/favicon.ico/
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i think we can do for generating the random token using the crypto:

```
var passwordResetToken = createRandomToken(data.body.email);

exports.createRandomToken = function (string) {
  var seed = crypto.randomBytes(20);
  return crypto.createHash('abcde').update(seed + string).digest('hex');
};
```